# How to reference ul element inside a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="main_tabs">
    <ul id="main_tabs_nav">
        <li class="sn1"><a id="divleftlink0" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:divActivate(0,2,'divleft');" class="active">Newsletter</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sn2"><a id="divleftlink1" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:divActivate(1,2,'divleft');" class="inactive">Get Social</a>
        </li>
        <li class="sn3"><a id="divleftlink2" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:divActivate(2,2,'divleft');" class="inactive">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I apply a CSS like this, and it works fine:

```
#main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a {
width: 107px;
background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/someimage.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

But this does not work:

```
#main_tabs #main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a {
width: 107px;
background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/someimage.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

How do I get the second piece of CSS code to work too ?

I want to put `#main_tabs` in the start of the CSS too, to strictly follow the hierarchy ..

Comment: It seems to work fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B2UTU/

Comment: This should work, are you sure this is *exactly* the code you're using?  Note also that it's not strictly necessary to prepend the parent `div`.  The child `div` is referenced by its `id` and `id`s are (or should be, according to spec) unique in the document, so any reference to an `id` is going to be absolute.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: +1 for strictly following hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your HTML and CSS. Both of these CSS styles work from a hierarchical standpoint. You can see that I added in another style to turn the first link red using the #main_tabs as the parent, and it is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KempfCreative/2WzmY/3/).

If you are looking to do text replacement, I would use this method instead:

```
li.sn1 a {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```